# hMailServer with Domain - WAMP

Tags: dns, smtp, wamp, mx-record, hmail-server

I came into a struggle the last few days.

Using WAMP Server and following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgs9gQ5k_qY) I set up a local email environment, and I wanted to make the emails reach accounts outside of the local host.

I heard you need to make some changes in the DNS zone, so here is my DNS Zone at Freenom.

[image]

Is is possible to make emails sent from a computer using hMailServer reach the outside world through a domain?

**Thank you for your time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but it depends on your Scenario.

If you are behind a Router or a NAT or a Dynamic IP-Address it's almost not possible
to run a real World sending SMTP-Server and you shouldn't

If you have a Hosting plan (your own Windows V-Server or Root server) with Remote Desktop
access and a static ip address it's and access to the DNS-Configuration of your Internet Domain, it is possible and recommended.

1) First you need to setup a DNS A Record which points to your static IP in DNS
2) You need to create DNS MX Record which points to your A Record

Now you can add a new hMailServer Domain and add accounts and sent Emails
out. But you should setup a DNS A Record for IMAP or POP3 as well so you can
Receive Emails and not only sending.

Comment: I do have a static IP address (paying extra for it :/ ), but I do not see why being behind a router would hinder my attempt to reach the outside world. I ended up setting up a separate computer with CentOS 7 and managed to set up an e-mail server. Your help on DNS was useful, so thank you about that. Now, what is currently stopping my server from working properly is that my IP range is in a few spam lists for some reason I am not aware. Still trying to reach my ISP about this...

Comment: That's one of the reasons you shouldn't try to send from a Dynamic IP. In most cases, such SMTP-Servers are Spammers and Dynamic IP's with DynDNS configured to it are blacklisted in no time. DynDNS could be a reason for blacklisting as well.

Comment: You see, the IP is not Dynamic, as this is a business-class internet connection and I am paying extra for a static public IP. I did manage to make it work on Windows, but only using some kind of mail relay, because of the Blacklists I mentioned above. Meanwhile, I put your advice to use and I also moved my DNS configuration over to Cloudflare for easier management. Thanks for your time, @Dravion. :)